# How to add circle with an on-hover text box to d3.js mulitline chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js v4 chart that consists of two lines. On one line (the green one below) I have a focus elements where a circle is created on focus and shows the relevant data.

For the orange line, I would like to have circles show at each data point by default (not on focus), and hovering over the circle should show the value of the orange line there.

[image: current d3.js v4 chart]

I have searched for solutions online, but all I find is single-line charts and/or focus elements and I've been unable to modify them for my purpose. I've gotten probably 10 different errors, and never managed to get the circles to even show.

To be clear, there should be a circle at every data point on the orange line (there are about 20 data points in the example above), the circle should show at all times - and only when hovering over the circle, a text box should show containing the value of the data point.

Here is my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/a6w89xhj/

The orange line is added as:

```
eps_data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
});

var orangeline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

g.append("path")
    .data([eps_data])
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', '#ff5628')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", orangeline);
```

Adding a circle here doesn't work. Adding it as a focus element isn't acceptable for my purpose. So I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the code below will mark each point on the eps-data line with a circle:

```
g.selectAll().data(eps_data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "data-circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr('fill', '#ff5628');
```

Here is a fork of your demo, with this code applied:

https://jsfiddle.net/ClientsideDesign/e2ky13wt/

This uses the 'enter' functionality of d3, which provides an (empty) placeholder for each point in the data set, which can then be appended to (in this case with a circle) and any child elements styled as required.

Further information about enter specifically and joins in D3 generally can be found [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Here is an additional demo, with value text on hover for both lines:

https://jsfiddle.net/ClientsideDesign/vcm7puq4/

I've worked within the structure of the code provided so there may scope to neaten things up. The final value on the line doesn't seem to show on hover, but this might be intentional?

With a tooltip on each point of the orange line:

```
g.selectAll().data(eps_data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "data-circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr('fill', '#ff5628')
  .on("mouseover", function (d) {
    addOrangeTooltip(d, x(d.date), y(d.value));
  });

//...

function addOrangeTooltip(d, x, y) {
  g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "eps-tooltip")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d.value)
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y);

// Remove trigger must come after text

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
      d3.select(this).remove();
      d3.selectAll(".eps-tooltip").remove();
    });
}
```

Demo on the link below. The mouseover functionality of the rectangle overlay needed some adjustment to work with the mouseover points on the eps-data line:

https://jsfiddle.net/ClientsideDesign/fvt4c3dz/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm here. Looking at the `enter` option now, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: That's an improvement, but not exactly what I was looking for. I don't want the two lines to be connected in this way. Currently, hovering over a vertical shows hover text for both lines. What I need is: hovering over the circle (not just anywhere on the vertical) displays the hover text for the orange line only. Otherwise, only the green line's text is displayed, like in the original example.

Comment: Ah I see - I'll pull something together. It's worth saying that this will be more complicated than it might be because of the rectangle you have across the whole graph, with the mouseover event.

Comment: I'm happy to get rid of the rectangle if I can keep the green line functioning as it is without it.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good! I will try implementing it in the morning, I've left my laptop for the day.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Matt Saunders was a lot faster than me... So I don't need to explain too much.

Anyway I tried to pimp the code and the graph a bit, but conceptually it is almost the same as Matt explained in his answer. I use the ´enter()´ function to create the placeholders and fill them with your data.

This is used for your money value and the date as well. Instead of appending the text on hovering, i show it by setting the opacity to 100%.

For example this is used to append the text, similar to appending a circle

```
svg.selectAll(null).data(data)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr('x', d => x(d.date) - 22)
    .attr('y', d => y(d.value) - 8)
    .attr('class', (d, i) => 'info-txt data-idx' + i)
    .style('display', d => isNaN(d.value) ? 'none' : null)
    .text(d => d.formatted_date)
```

Just find the complete fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Iamnino/6aw9fjLq/39/

**Edit**
Just a side note: I did not work with your exact code. I wrote it more or less on my own, so there might be some variables of yours I don't use...